# How to get relative data for each row Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have the following request:

```php
$results = ResultTest::with("client", "doctor.distributor")
    ->whereIn("client_id", $transaction_items_unique_codes)
    ->get();
```

It returns me array of result.
After I need to get additional data for each returned array item and join it to one result:

```php
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $conclusion = Conclusion::where("type_work", $result->type_work)
        ->where("category", $result->category)
        ->firstOrFail();
    
    $types = Work::orderBy('name')->get()->pluck('name', 'id');
}
```

Problem is `$results` contains more 100 rows, so it has issues with 100 requests to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a `leftJoin`?

```php
$results = ResultTest::query()
    ->with([
        'client',
        'doctor.distributor'
    ])
    ->leftJoin('conclusions c', function ($join) {
        $join->on('result_tests.type_works', 'c.type_works')
             ->on('result_tests.category', 'c.category')
    })
    ->whereIn('client_id', $transaction_items_unique_codes)
    ->get();
```

If it was just one condition, you could create a relationship and eager load it but as far as I can think of at the moment, Eloquent doesn't support defining a relationship that depends on multiple columns.